# R Shiny add zoom functionality to ggplot dotplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

I have a shiny app displaying a ggplot dotplot of columns to choice from the iris dataset. How can I add a **zoom functionality** to the plot, being able to zoom in and out of the plot? Possible with a doubleclick or by moving the mouse wheel?

I have already tried using plotly, but have not been successful in this because the plot never showed up correctly.

```
library(shiny)
library(readxl)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggrepel)
library(dplyr)


ui = fluidPage(
  
  br(),
  
  fluidRow(
    
    column(width = 2, # 2/12
           varSelectInput("variablex", "Trait x:", iris[1:4]),
           varSelectInput("variabley", "Trait y:", iris[1:4]),
           varSelectInput("variabledot", "Trait dot size:", iris[1:4]),
           
           #> plot dimensions
           
           textInput(
             inputId ="plotdim"
             , label = "Dimensions (W*H*dpi)"
             , placeholder = "W*H*dpi"
             , value = "35*25*100"
           ),
           
           br(), # Add a line break for spacing
           
           column(width = 2, # 2/12
                  downloadButton("download_pdf", "Download as PDF")
           )
    ),
    
    column(width = 10, # 10/12   
           #> render as PDF
           uiOutput("plotui")
    )
    
  ),
)


server = function(input, output) {

  
  culturename<-"Iris"
  Speciesname<-iris$Species[1]

  # plot reactive
  plot <- reactive({
    ggplot(iris, aes(x=!!input$variablex, y=!!input$variabley)) +
      geom_point(aes(size=!!input$variabledot), pch=21) +
      theme_grey(base_size = 22) +
      theme(legend.position = "right") +
      guides(fill = guide_legend(override.aes = list(size=3)))
  })
  # plot render
  output$plot <- renderImage({
    dim <- input$plotdim %>% 
      strsplit(., "[*]") %>% 
      unlist() %>% as.numeric()
    if(length(dim) < 3) stop("Need W*H*dpi")
    outfile <- tempfile(fileext = ".png")
    png(outfile, width = dim[1], height = dim[2], units = "cm", res = dim[3])
    print(plot())
    dev.off()
    list(src = outfile)
  }, deleteFile = TRUE)
  # Save PDF
  output$download_pdf <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function(){
      paste(culturename,"_",Speciesname,".pdf",sep="")
    },
    content = function(file){
      pdf(file, width = 20, height = 13)
      print(plot())
      dev.off()
    }
  )
  #> render ui in the server
  output$plotui <- renderUI({
    tagList(
      div(imageOutput("plot"), align = "center"),
    )
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: See https://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/plot-interaction-zoom.html

Comment: I didn't manage to do it with my code. Could you try it and post it as an answer?